# How do I make css offset smoother with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Player controller using the position attributes and javascript but it is kinda snappy. What do I do?

I tried making an infinite loop then adding a time out to slow it down to the client's computers frames but it just outputted the same result, snappy. Also, I wrote this in Atom and I compiled it on the Google Chrome Web Browser.

**Javascript**

```
var player = document.getElementById('Player');
var ctx = player.getContext("2d");
var playerXPos = 0;
var playerYPos = 0;
var playerSpeed = 5;
ctx.fillStyle = "Red";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,50,50);

function animate(key) {
  if (key.keyCode == 39) { //Right Arrow
    playerXPos += playerSpeed;
    player.style.left = playerXPos + "px";
  }
  if (key.keyCode == 37) { //Left Arrow
    playerXPos -= playerSpeed;
    player.style.left = playerXPos + "px";
  }
  if (key.keyCode == 38) { //Up Arrow
    playerYPos -= playerSpeed;
    player.style.top = playerYPos + "px";
  }
  if (key.keyCode == 40) { //Down Arrow
    playerYPos += playerSpeed;
    player.style.top = playerYPos + "px";
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}

document.onkeydown = animate;
```

**HTML part** *(lol html is not a programming language but whatever)*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Player Test</title>
  <style>
    #Player {
      position: relative;
    }
  </style>
<body>
  <canvas id="Player"></canvas>
  <script src="App/playerController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want it to be smooth. I think I should use linear algebra but I am not that advance in javascript. I am actually a beginner.

Comment: You could use CSS Transitions or a JS Animation library like anime.js

Comment: How would I impliment CSS Transitions?

Comment: css transitions are well documented, like many other aspects of HTML, Javascript and CSS, [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) - I would recommend using MDN as the go to source for all your web developer needs :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the CSS transition property to get a smoother effect. You need to set the initial top and left positions of your element in your CSS since these are the properties that you are changing with your JS. I've set the animation to last 0.5s, but this can be adjusted to be faster or slower as you'd prefer:

```js
var player = document.getElementById('Player');
var ctx = player.getContext("2d");
var playerXPos = 0;
var playerYPos = 0;
var playerSpeed = 5;
ctx.fillStyle = "Red";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);

function animate(key) {
  if (key.keyCode == 39) { //Right Arrow
    playerXPos += playerSpeed;
    player.style.left = playerXPos + "px";
  }
  if (key.keyCode == 37) { //Left Arrow
    playerXPos -= playerSpeed;
    player.style.left = playerXPos + "px";
  }
  if (key.keyCode == 38) { //Up Arrow
    playerYPos -= playerSpeed;
    player.style.top = playerYPos + "px";
  }
  if (key.keyCode == 40) { //Down Arrow
    playerYPos += playerSpeed;
    player.style.top = playerYPos + "px";
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

document.onkeydown = animate;
```

```css
#Player {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="Player"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
var player = document.getElementById('Player');
var ctx = player.getContext("2d");
var playerXPos = 0;
var playerYPos = 0;
var playerXSpeed = 0;
var playerYSpeed = 0;
ctx.fillStyle = "Red";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,50,50);

setInterval(function(){
    playerXPos += playerXSpeed;
    player.style.left = playerXPos + "px";
    playerYPos += playerYSpeed;
    player.style.top = playerYPos + "px";
},5)

function animate(event) {
    let x = event.which || event.keyCode
    switch (x) {
        case 39://Right Arrow
        playerXSpeed = 1
            break
        case 37://Left Arrow
        playerXSpeed = -1
            break
        case 38://Up Arrow
        playerYSpeed = -1;
            break
        case 40://Down Arrow
        playerYSpeed = 1;
            break
    }
}

document.onkeydown = animate;
document.onkeyup = function(){
    let x = event.which || event.keyCode
    switch (x) {
        case 39://Right Arrow
        case 37://Left Arrow
            playerXSpeed = 0
            break
        case 38://Up Arrow
        case 40://Down Arrow
            playerYSpeed = 0;
            break
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up using keyframes to make it move smoother